# wordpress 3.4.1 muti-sites image has not appear in time on safari sometimes

Tags: html, image, wordpress, nginx, safari

I'm running muti-sites wordpress with nginx, and test on safari (chrome is fine).

A very important thing is, the image is upload by administrator.

I found sometime some image has not appear immediately, I was just thing a about network trouble before, but I found the rule today.

the rule is:

1. enter the page, image shown.
2. refresh the page(Command + R), image disappeared.
3. refresh again, image shown.
4. again again, it disappeared.
5. loops....

NOTICE: disappeared is means that's not apear immediately: loaded the page about 2 second later, the image could be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refresh the page, safari send a image request to server with HTTP header `HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH` and `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE`.

Because of this is a mutiple site, nginx rewrite the request to ms-files.php to process it. ms-files.php found the image has not been modified, so it's response 304 with no content.

The bug is, the ms-files.php has already set `Content-Length` header before decided to response 304, so the response header going to be 304 with no content and `Content-Length > 0`. After that, safari was down.

Fixed the bug by add `header( 'Content-Length: 0' );` to wp-includes/ms-files.php line 79.

```
 75 if ( ( $client_last_modified && $client_etag )
 76     ? ( ( $client_modified_timestamp >= $modified_timestamp) && ( $client_etag == $etag ) )
 77     : ( ( $client_modified_timestamp >= $modified_timestamp) || ( $client_etag == $etag ) )
 78     ) {
 79     header( 'Content-Length: 0' );
 80     status_header( 304 );
 81     exit;
 82 }
```

Comment: Is there a bug reported for this here http://core.trac.wordpress.org/? Modifying the core code isn't recommended since it will be overwritten on upgrade, but if it's truly a bug it should be patched.